# Mocking a supplier returning null instead of value

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to write a test for a method which uses a supplier inside.
The code is somethings like

```
class TestClass {

private Supplier<SomeConfigClass> configSupplier;

testMethod() {
    int value = configSupplier.get().getSomeValue();
    // business logic using the value.
}
```

The unit test is as follows

```
configSupplier = configuration = () -> mock(SomeConfigClass); // this is injected via

TestClass ob = new TestClass(configSupplier);

// the mock
when(configSupplier.get().getSomeValue()).thenReturn(1);

// call
ob.testMethod();

// verify calls
...
```

When I mock a normal `SomeConfigClass` object then the `.getSomeValue()` returns 1 correctly but when I use a supplier the `configSupplier.get().getSomeValue()` returns `null`.
Note that the `configSupplier.get()` returns a mock of `SomeConfigClass` correctly (checked by evaluating expression in IDE.)

Comment: do you mock `getSomeValue` in your mock of `SomeConfigClass`? I don't see in your posted code where you indicate that this should return 1

Comment: Thanks @njzk2 adding that worked. had totally missed it. I will take a break now :)